# How to handle auto direction of text with dart-flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, nlp, bloc, firebase-mlkit

I need to make **auto-detection for posts language** to change the text direction according to language, I Used *'firebase_mlkit_language.dart'* to make the auto-detection of language.

this is a screenshot of screen:
[image]

I need the English post alignment to be from ltr.

**this Function I made to check lang**

```
Future<String> checkLang(String text)async{
  final LanguageIdentifier languageIdentifier = FirebaseLanguage.instance.languageIdentifier();
  final List<LanguageLabel> labels = await languageIdentifier.processText(text);
  for (LanguageLabel label in labels) {
    final String text = label.languageCode;
    final double confidence = label.confidence;
  }
  return labels[0].languageCode;
}
```

while *getposts* function is processing and get the posts from firebase, **I added this line  to get a list of posts language**

```
 postsLang.add(checkLang(PostModel.fromJson(element.data()).text).toString());
```

then while generating the posts UI, in the post widget i made this condition to check whether the language is Arabic *'ar'*
so, the direction should be from right to left.

```
textDirection: AppCubit.get(context).postsLang[index].toString() == 'ar' ?TextDirection.rtl:TextDirection.ltr,
```